# remote `mac` refuse the ssh connection from the local computer

Tags: mac, ssh

This problem confuse me a lot.
What I had done:

1. open `remote` router port forwarding.

: when I type `ssh *@***` in the `local` computer, the `remote` router log shows

> [LAN access from remote] from `*.*.*.*`:37482 to 192.168.0.16:22

`*.*.*.*` is `local` computer ip

2. open `remote login` in the remote `Mac`

But I can't ssh into the `remote mac` computer.

In the `local` computer, it shows

```
OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Connecting to `*.*.*.*` [remote mac] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/AAA/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

While in the `remote` mac computer, I tail the system log. it shows

```
Jan 15 19:10:57 AAA com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.BBBBB-BBBB): Service instances do not support events yet.
Jan 15 19:10:57 AAA.local sshd[3539]: error: BSM audit: getaddrinfo failed for UNKNOWN: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Jan 15 19:10:57 AAA.local sshd[3539]: Could not write ident string to UNKNOWN
Jan 15 19:10:57 AAA com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.BBBBB-BBBB[3539]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution?

Comment: @gregseth not yet.

Comment: Did you check your firewall? You must allow `launchd` to accept incoming external (non-LAN) connexions. That's what caused my problem.

Comment: @gregseth could you give some tips about how you give the launchd permission?

Comment: I'm using Little Snitch as firewall, so it's pretty straightforward: add a new rule, choose program, protocol/ports, and allow on deny connection. With the default system firewall, I don't really know…

Comment: @gregseth Little Snitch, too. May be that reason. Thank you very much